# Substring and Grouping issue in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<InterSection criteria="Microsoft-ASP">value</Intersection>
<InterSection criteria="Microsoft-MVC">value</Intersection>
<InterSection criteria="HP-MVC">value</Intersection>
```

I need to create TOC at top of my HTML page and so I need to group by criteria (First part before '-').

I need distinct values like

1. Microsoft
2. HP

My XSLT have following code

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:text>#trigger</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="substring-before(@Criteria, ' - ')">
                      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@Criteria, ' - ')"/> 
                      <xsl:text>
                      </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>        

  </a>
```

But somehow i am getting

1. Microsoft
2. Microsoft
3. HP

instead of 
1. Microsoft
2. HP

I have following written in my XSLT

```
  <xsl:template match="InterSection" mode="TOC">

<li>
  <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:text>#trigger</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="substring-before(@Criteria, ' - ')">
        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()"/>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Your work is a mess: case is not preserved (e.g. `InterSection` closes with `Intersection`), you use `Criteria` in the template while in the input you have `criteria`, you were taking the substring with spaces (' - '). You don't have spaces between the hyphen ('-').

Comment: I've finally tried to summarize all the problems I would fix in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finally going to summarize the problems I would fix in your work in order to make it work (deleted previous edits):

- your input xml elements are not in correct case
- in your transform you refer to the attribute `criteria`using the wrong case
- your `substring` expression contains too much spaces around the second argument `-`
- you should use `current-grouping-key()` to get the value of the current matching group
- the template must match the parent of `InterSection` (`Root`) and then you have to iterate on `InterSection` like you would do with `xsl:for-each`

Comment: It's hard understand what you are doing wrong, starting from fragments you provided. Make sure to clean up your code as suggested in my comment above, and check my edits to see how grouping works. Hope it helps.

Comment: i have modified code sample on original question, still getting same result

Comment: Your `substring` expression still contains spaces around the `-`.

Comment: Ok, I see now. You are grouping on the match of the node. That's not correct.

Comment: having only   <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="substring-before(@Criteria, '-')">
   <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
also gives same result

Comment: i am using <xsl:template match="InterSection" mode="TOC"> so what should i type in place of .? i tried Root/InterSection which just gives me 1.2.3., InterSection Node is child of <Root>

Comment: Then match on `Root`. See my edit. If doesnt work change processor, i give up.

Comment: I went through it carefully and you were right. I am getting grouping perfect now but now getting different issue. Only grouping appear. Nothing else is appearing. Can you provide me email address so i can send you XML and XSLT?

Comment: Start accepting the answer (and upvoting if you like) as a good SO member would do. Then create a new question trying to be clear in what you want to obtain and starting from which data. I'll be glad to help you if I can and when possible. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
           <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="substring-before(@Criteria, ' - ')">
```

**This is meaningless. The expression in the `select` attribute selects a single item**. Grouping has meaning when there are more than one items selected and we want to group them using certain criteria.

When a single item is "grouped" the "result" is always that same item -- this is exactly what you get.

**Solution**: Select correctly a group of items to be grouped. Or, use this alternative solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vallKeys" select=
  "distinct-values
      (/*/*/@criteria
            /substring-before(.,'-')
      )
  "/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="$vallKeys">
   <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(position(),'.',.,'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (derived from the provided fragment by corrected its severe malformedness):

```
<someParent>
    <InterSection criteria="Microsoft-ASP">value</InterSection>
    <InterSection criteria="Microsoft-MVC">value</InterSection>
    <InterSection criteria="HP-MVC">value</InterSection>
</someParent>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
1.Microsoft
2.HP
```